# Material UI Autocomplete implementation with options containing array of objects (ID and label)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using **Material UI Autocomplete** for my project. As shown in [official documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/), my options are,

```js
let options = [
   { id: "507f191e810c19729de860ea", label: "London" },
   { id: "u07f1u1e810c19729de560ty", label: "Singapore" },
   { id: "lo7f19re510c19729de8r090", label: "Dhaka" },
]
```

Then, I am using `Autocomplete` as,

```js
import React, { Component, Fragment, useState } from "react"
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';
import options from "/options"

function SelectLocation(props){
    const [ input, setInput ] = useState("");

    const getInput = (event,val) => {
        setInput(val);
    }

    return (
        <Autocomplete
            value={input}
            options={options}
            renderOption={option => <Fragment>{option.label}</Fragment>}}
            getOptionLabel={option => option.label}
            renderInput={params => {
                return (
                    <TextField 
                        {...params} 
                        label={props.label} 
                        variant="outlined" 
                        fullWidth
                    />
                )
            }}
            onInputChange={getInput}
        />
    )
}
```

Now my UI (options list) is showing what I expected. **The problem is**, I am getting `London` or `Singapore` as a value of my `input`, but I want to get the selected object or `ID` from this input.

I've followed their documentation thoroughly, but couldn't find a way!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`onInputChange` get's fired with the *actual content* of the input.

You might want to use the `onChange` event exposed by the [input props](https://material-ui.com/api/input/#props), which will return the selected element. The id should then be available as `val.id` in your `getInput` callback.

Answer (score 0):

For others that might have the same issues as I. In case your option are array of objects (or any other data structure), use the following:

`getOptionLabel` new api of autoComplete will allow for you to select any option value from your data source.

Example

```
<SearchInput
  getOptionLabel={(option) => option["whateverKeyYouNeed"]}
  .
  .
  .
  .
/>
```

More here >>> https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/